# How Do You Flush Cached Images on iOS Emulators

Tags: maui

In one part of my app, I have four images, and I noticed that only two of them were displaying correctly on iOS, but all four worked on Android.  After digging around, I noticed that the file extensions on the two that weren't displaying were uppercase, and I think all images need to be all lower case.  So I changed the filenames in the project to all lower case and redeployed.  Didn't work.  Tried a few variations that didn't work, and finally made a copy of the images with a lower case extension and it worked.

Now I've made some changes to the images and copied them over the old ones in the project file.  When I deploy it though, the app on iOS shows the old image. Both of these problems seem as though they could be resolved if I could flush out the cache or whatever is holding these images in the iOS emulators.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: either delete the app from the simulator, or just reset the entire simulator image

Comment: I tried both of these, and neither worked.  I restarted the host machine and it didn't work.  I finally renamed the images again in my project and ran it again, and it shows the correct image now.  But I can't continue to rename every time an image changes, so wondering where these items are cached.

Comment: you might try cleaning and rebuilding your solution, its possible the old versions are not getting overwritten at build time

Comment: Thanks Jason, I did that, and also manually deleted the contents of the debug and obj folders and the images started working.  Thank you!